# Positioning UISwitch in UITableViewCell to right

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiswitch

may I know how to positioning the UISwitch in UITableViewCell to right? I'm not using storyboard to add the Switch Button!

[image]

> Here is the code in controller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:note];

    //TableView Cell Background Images
    cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];

    //add switch button start
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UISwitch *aSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    [aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];
    //add switch button end

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You have a very common problem - cells get reused. Every time you scroll, the reused cell will get another new slider. You will keep adding more and more switches to each cell.

Comment: yeah that is what i want. Every cell has it own switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this....

```
UISwitch *aSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(225.0, 0.0, 80.0, 45.0)];
[aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
aSwitch.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame (or the center). But also:

1. Create and add the switch when you create the cell, otherwise you will have multiple switches in the cell
2. Configure the cell after you ensure it exists

Something like:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //add switch button start
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        //TableView Cell Background Images
        cell.backgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];

        cell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 44);

        // Configure the cell...
        UISwitch *aSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
        aSwitch.tag = 123123;

        CGRect switchFrame = aSwitch.frame;
        switchFrame.origin.x = 200 - switchFrame.size.width;
        switchFrame.origin.y = 22 - (switchFrame.size.height * 0.5);
        aSwitch.frame = switchFrame;

        [aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];
        //add switch button end
    }

    // configure the cell
    NSString *note = [self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:note];

    // configure the switch
    UISwitch *aSwitch = (UISwitch *)[cell viewWithTag:123123];
    aSwitch. ...;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could subclass UITableCellView and add the UISwitch and set its frame in the there. That way, all you have to do is set the target and action in cellForRowAtIndexPath.